# ASP button is creating a DIV Tag and are not aligning in-line

Tags: asp.net, html

I am facing a bizzare issue. The asp:Buttons are creating div tags and are aligning vertically but not horizontally. I want them to align horizontally or in css way "inline". can anyone suggest a work around to this one. or can you tell me what I need to do get things working. All other asp buttons are aligning inline in the page except of these three.
The alignment issue is in IE 7-9.
Things look good in Chrome and Firefox

This is the markup in asp:

```
<td class="FieldsetButtons" align="right">
                <asp:Button id="y" runat="server" Width="100px"  Text="Apply"
                    Enabled="False" onclick="y_Click" ValidationGroup="mail" 
                    meta:resourcekey="yResource1"></asp:Button>
                <asp:Button id="p" runat="server" Width="100px"  Text="Verify" 
                    ENABLED="False" onclick="p_Click"  ValidationGroup="mail" 
                    meta:resourcekey="pResource1"></asp:Button>
                <asp:Button id="l" runat="server" Width="100px"  Text="Reset" 
                    CausesValidation="false" onclick="l_Click" 
                    meta:resourcekey="lResource1"></asp:Button>

    </td>
```

This is the markup that is being created in HTML:

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lServer1_yPanel">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lServer1$y" value="@Apply@" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lServer1_y" disabled="disabled" style="width:100px;" />
    </div>
                <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lServer1_pPanel">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lServer1$p" value="@Verify@" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lServer1_p" disabled="disabled" style="width:100px;" />
    </div>
                <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lServer1_lPanel">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lServer1$l" value="@Reset@" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lServer1_l" style="width:100px;" />
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the lServer1 control? Does it ListView, GridView or some similar control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float them all to the left or right.

Add this to your style sheet:

```
.FieldsetButtons div {float:right;width:100px;}
```

That will make all child divs align horizontally right and should be browser friendly.

Answer (score 0):

What does your style class FieldsetButtons contain? My guess is that something in your CSS is messing it up. Maybe consider using Firebug to determine what style is affecting the layout of those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you could use table inside  and create a single row in it with 3 columns...

`

`

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the meta:resourcekey tags are generating the divs to be able to apply styling from the resource file, but i have not tested this theory. Have you tried a test without the meta:resourcekey tags to see if the divs go away?